# Is it possible to redirect the "Server not found" page to another website?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I want to make my computer redirect to some website say "www.google.com" if I type in the address bar a domain name that it doesnt exist.

I'm not asking for the code, I just want to know whether this is possible. and If yes, any hints on how I can do this would be highly appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Yes, it's possible. Check customErrors section in web.config

Comment: is it a `winforms` question really?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Server not found" is not a [404 error](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_404). According to Wikipedia:

> 404 errors should not be confused with DNS errors, which appear when the given URL refers to a server name that does not exist

In regard to your question, the only way to perform the action you describe is to change the behavior of the browser; changing the source code.

Answer (score 0):

You can configure it in the web.config. Update the `statusCode` with the correct error code returned.

```
<customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="~/Error/GenericErrorPage.aspx">

     <error statusCode="error code" redirect="~/Error/CustomPage.aspx" />

</customErrors>
```

Comment: Do I have to create a web.config file in C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\CONFIG ?

Answer (score 0):

```
<system.webServer>
    <httpErrors errorMode="Custom" existingResponse="Replace">
      <remove statusCode="404" subStatusCode="-1" />
      <error statusCode="404" subStatusCode="-1" prefixLanguageFilePath="" path="http://google.com" responseMode="Redirect" />
    </httpErrors>
</system.webServer>
```

Comment: Do I have to create a web.config file in C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\CONFIG ?